# Convert Table Text to Number

Tags: javascript

I am making a scorekeeper. 
What is supposed to happen is this:
Assume the row was "1"

1. User presses a button.
2. Javascript detects which button was pressed.
3. Javascript gets that corresponding row and gets its value.
4. Javascript turns that value into an integer.
5. Javascript adds 1 to it.
6. Javascript updates the row.

Result:
2
3
4
5
...

What happens: 
01
011
0111
01111
011111
...
This is what the row looks like:

| Score | ⏺ is a button |
| --- | --- |
| ScoreRow is the class of the row. | ⏺ |

This is my code:

```
  function Add() { 
// This is the function
    AddData = AddRow.dataset.id
// Gets the row number that was assigned by another script which is not shown because it is quite long.
    var Change = document.getElementsByClassName("ScoreRow")[AddData].innerHTML;
// Defines variable Change as the corresponding row's content.
    Number(Change);
// Turns Change into an interger
    Change = Change + 1;
// Adds 1 to Change
    document.getElementsByClassName("ScoreRow")[AddData].innerHTML = Change;
// Updates the row to Change (which is +1)
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Number(Change)` does not mutate the variable... it returns a new value... try `Change = Number(Change);`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Don't know why I didn't see that. Thank you soo much! 